# analytic solution to a symmetric system of nonlinear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve this PDE system analytically, as in the equations?

$u_x(x,y)=1+\exp(u(x,y)+v(x,y))$

$v_y(x,y)=1+\exp(u(x,y)+v(x,y))$

where subscripts are partial derivatives.

Comment: You'd need some boundary conditions to go anywhere with this, but notice that $u_x-v_y=0$

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution to fit general boundary conditions. What can be inferred from $u_x-v_y=0$

Comment: Not the general solution but at least some solutions : $$\begin{cases}
u(x,y)=-\frac{b}{a+b}\ln \left|e^{\left( \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)(ax+by+c)}-1\right| \\
v(x,y)=-\frac{a}{a+b}\ln \left|e^{\left( \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)(ax+by+c)}-1\right|\\
\text{any}\quad a,b,c \quad\text{except}\quad a=0\:;\:b=0\:;\:a+b=0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @JJacquelin thanks so much